# Handling multiple line subtitles of Right aligned languages(arabic) in Moviepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, imagemagick, moviepy

I am trying to add Arabic subtitles on a video using Moviepy. The issue I'm facing is related to alignment of Arabic text, as it progresses from right to left, instead of left to right in English language.

[image]

As text length gets more and more, Moviepy trims the words from both ends, this issue can be resolved if we break the text into multiple lines. This works well for English language but for Arabic, the first line becomes the last line because of the (Right-Left)alignment.

[image]

The text on Second line should come first on the first line at the start, while end chuck of first text towards the left corner should render on the second line, but it is getting rendered as English language, Left to right alignment.

Here is my code:

```
def add_subtitles(address_subtitles, address_video):
  video = VideoFileClip(address_video)
  generator = lambda txt: TextClip(txt, font='Arial', fontsize=22, color='black', stroke_width=2, method='caption', align='south', size=video.size)
  subtitles = SubtitlesClip(address_subtitles, generator)
  #print()

  result = CompositeVideoClip([video, subtitles.set_pos(('center','bottom'))])
  result.write_videofile("arabic_with_hardcoded_subtitles_3.mp4", fps=video.fps, temp_audiofile="temp-audio.m4a", remove_temp=True, codec="libx264"
  , audio_codec="aac")
```